# Magento2: Can I import product attributes in a CSV file to edit their Storefront Property values?

Tags: magento2, attributes, import, csv, edit

Can I import product attributes in a CSV file to edit their Storefront Property values?

Comment: Yes, simply create CSV file with SKU vs Attributes to change assign/add values to attribute for any product.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can mention the store ids in "store_view_code" attribute of product CSV.